# Stack Overflow is planning to give their theoretical AI/ML questions wholesale to Cross Validated

Tags: discussion, migration

Just a note that Stack Overflow is looking to give away their closed questions on theoretical aspects of AI/ML to Cross Validated:

- [Let's gift wrap our (good) Machine Learning theory questions for Cross Validated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404799/lets-gift-wrap-our-good-machine-learning-theory-questions-for-cross-validated) (SO Meta)
- [Would Cross Validated want Machine Learning Theory questions that are no longer on-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/would-cross-validated-want-machine-learning-theory-questions-that-are-no-longer) (CV Meta)

I guess that AI SE would be also interested in hosting some of these questions, hence this post here.

I was not at all involved (in fact I have argued in SO Meta that we should keep them there, but I am clearly with the minority), but to the best of my knowledge, no other relevant SE site (namely AI and Data Science) has been asked if they would be possibly interested to receive some of them, too.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. I don't know what others think about this, but I would be interested in questions related to reinforcement learning, artificial intelligence, evolutionary computation, so I would definitely not mind having them migrated to AI SE.

Comment: In my personal experience, it's difficult to decide what AI questions belong on Cross Validated vs ai.stackexchange, but I think it's likely that a significant amount of them on stackoverflow probably belong here. When I ask AI-related questions, I've started differentiating between questions that are significantly based on statistics, such as statistical learning questions and many statistical-learning-leaning ML questions, and questions that are not, such as computer-science-leaning ML questions (architecture questions, algorithms questions, higher-level ML considerations, etc.).